# Loop em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso quando apagar de uma linha de uma lista. ele altere um input itens.

Exemplo:

```
linha 01
linha 02
linha 03
```

se eu apagar a linha dois atualmente ele fica:

```
linha 01
linha 03
```

mas não queria dessa forma eu preciso que ele altere e deixe assim:

```
linha 01
linha 02
```

então pensei em fazer assim:

```
for (i = 1; i < quantidadeTR; i++) {
    $("input:text[name^='item']").val(i);           
}
```

quantidadeTR = é igual ao total de linha pego por uma função.

com o código acima tenho o resultado:

```
linha 02
linha 02
```

Tentei assim também mas dá o mesmo erro:

```
var count = 1;
    while ( count < quantidadeTR ) {        
        $("input:text[name^='item']").val(count);
    count++;
    };
```

Comment: Eu não sei exatamente o que tem nessa tabela, mas se fizer sentido substituí-la por uma lista ordenada `<ol>`, a numeração iria se ajustar automaticamente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você faz uma *query* dessas em jQuery e chama o método `val`, você afeta **todos** os itens que atendem a query. Por isso todas as linhas ficam com o mesmo texto.

Os objetos jQuery possuem uma função [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), que itera sobre todos os itens obtidos pela query. Para ela você passa uma função que recebe dois parâmetros: o primeiro é o índice do elemento corrente e o segundo é o próprio elemento corrente. O que você quer é algo como:

```
$("input:text[name^='item']").each(function (index, elem) {
    $(elem).val(index);
});
```